# How to run an electron app with arguments?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

My app is electron with a `BrowserWindow` loading a local page index.html.
I call `npm run start` a script to run `electron main.js` , the app opens and the html loaded.
Can I add an argument to the script that will load different html file into the `BrowserWindow` ?

In the main.js file the code is :

```js
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences:{
      webSecurity:false
    },
    fullscreen : false });//, alwaysOnTop : true , kiosk : true })
  mainWindow.setMenu(null);
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  let url = `file://${__dirname}/index.html`; \\ index.html should be determined by argument passed at start.  
  mainWindow.loadURL(url,loadOptions);

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}
```

Comment: Is `process.argv` not populated?

Comment: Yes but how do I pass an argument of my, like -html=index2.html

Answer (score 10):

To pass the command line arguments to electron app:

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron main.js --arg1=value --arg2=value
```

It can be retrieved like this in the **main.js**:

```
import { app } from "electron";
app.commandLine.getSwitchValue("arg1");
app.commandLine.getSwitchValue("arg2");
```

Answer (score 4):

The way of passing arguments will be same, the only thing you have to take care is path of electron. In `package.json` its written `npm` start will perform `electron main.js`. So you will have to execute this command explicitly and pass arguments with "proper path of electron" i.e `./node_modules/.bin/electron`. Then the command will be

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron main.js argv1 argv2
```

and these arguments you can access by `process.argv` in `main.js`

and If wish you to access these parameters in your app then there are following things to do :

1.In your main.js define a variable like

```
     global.sharedObject = {prop1: process.argv}
```

2.In your app just include remote and use this `sharedObject`

```
    var remote = require('electron').remote,
      arguments = remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').prop1;

    console.log(arguments);
```

3.Output will be `["argv1", "argv2"]`

Source : https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-pass-command-arguments-in-electron/17247

Comment: For some people who struggled with this, don't forget to set in your console: > set ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=true

Answer (score 0):

**UninstallDisplayName**

> This lets you specify a custom name for the program's entry in the
>   Add/Remove Programs Control Panel applet. The value may include
>   constants. If this directive is not specified or is blank, Setup will
>   use the value of **[Setup]** section directive **AppVerName** for the name.

```
"build": {
  "nsis": {
    "uninstallDisplayName": "Your app name..."
  }
}
```

**Read more:**

[NSIS](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis)

[UninstallDisplayName](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstalldisplayname)